# How to get diagonal subdivisions in path curvature

Tags: mesh, add-on, bevel, path, loop

I want to make diagonal subdivision of my path curvature but it doesnt seem that blender has that option?
[image]

It should look like this
[image]

Comment: can u pls show a sketch/picture how it should look like?

Comment: I updated my question with picture explaining how it should look like.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you right, just use your curve, in object data properties -> bevel -> object -> use another curve, which you subdivide as much as you want, and you will get:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works for subdivisions but it gives random tilt to my main object

Comment: did you make the one curve (subdivided) totally straight? if yes, pls provide blend file so i can check it out